# How to download Gparted

Tags: gparted

I have a 64gb usb stick and it's now corrupting files that I place on it. On my previous computer I had Gparted (PCLinux) and that did the trick for a bit. Now I have Ubuntu I can't seem to find Gparted.

Is there an addon store for Ubuntu where I can find Gparted? Or is the another way to fix my usb stick?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I am at the final stages but now I can't seem to enter my password at the terminal using sudo. I have looked on the forum but none work

Answer (score 0):

You can install this via the terminal (or find it in software center):

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: Hi I am at the final stages but now I can't seem to enter my password at the terminal using sudo. I have looked on the forum but none work

Comment: When entering your password you will not see any chars (like asterixes) appear, that is normal. Type your pass and click enter, it should work.

Comment: Got it!!! when I typed in my password I didn't even get asterixes. I just typed it in and now it works. Thanks again.